# Deleting rows results in mysql error

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I want to delete the terminal_id from my tmp_table

I use this code:

> DELETE terminal_id FROM tmp_table

I don't know why it says unknown terminal_id when I have a terminal_id column on my tmp_table. I even double check the spelling.

Comment: Delete operates on rows, not columns.

Comment: just omit the terminal_id and it should work

Comment: @Zaffy that would delete the table.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO No it will just truncate the table but thats what your query does or not ? If you want to delete values in some column consider using `UPDATE` instead,

Answer (score 2):

The proper syntax for deleting rows from MySQL is:

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE] FROM tbl_name
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]
```

If you're attempting to drop a column, you need to use the `ALTER` syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE tmp_table DROP terminal_id
```

If you want to delete the data inside column `terminal_id`, you need to use the `UPDATE` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE` deletes rows. To remove a column you have to use `ALTER TABLE` like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `tmp_table` DROP `terminal_id`
```

To unset the entire all the column values, but keep the row, you can do the following:

```
UPDATE `tmp_table` SET `terminal_id` = NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want delete your column, it's an [**`ALTER TABLE`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) you need

```
ALTER TABLE tmp_table
 DROP terminal_id
```

> ALTER TABLE changes the structure of a table.